# DynamoDB Table Structure for Admin Panel/User Logins

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've been working with RMDB's for decades but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the "right way" to structure a specific data-model using DynamoDB. I'm completely new to NoSQL but I understand I should try to create as few tables as I can to accomplish my needs and the structure will depend on how I plan on querying the database. I've attached an image of the table relationship I would create in a relational database [relational db table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzcNx.png) to accomplish my application requirements, which are:

- The application will have multiple organizations
- Organizations can have zero-or-more staff members
- Staff can be associated to one-or-more organization
- Staff can have an independent role for each of their organization associations

Some Queries the data-model will need to support:

- Lookup Staff member based on email address (for login)
- Lookup Staff member based on ID (for RESTful API reference)
- Lookup Organization based on ID (for RESTful API reference)

Any help in the right direction would be great and maybe a great reference for DynamoDB design?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the re:invent talks by Rick Houlihan on YouTube and also the DynamoDB book by Alex DeBrie.

Comment: You're off to a great start by understanding your data model needs to match your application's access patterns.  I'd suggest creating a more complete list of access patterns (queries) that you'll need to support.  Why?  The access patterns you have listed are fairly simple.  However, once you create them, you'll ask yourself "What if I need to update the user's email address?" or "How can I find all staff members in an organization?"  And just like that, you've discovered additional more access patterns that will change your data model!